# Using node-rdkafka 2.5.1 version in my code to connect to kafka and it is crashing the connection after some time

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

From Node.js application I am trying to connect to Apache Kafka brokers(Version 0.11.0.3) using node-rdkafka client. The application is able to connect to kafka, subscribe to topics for a while but suddenly I see following error after about 1 and a half days in the logs(notice the timestamp). After these logs I can no longer see any successful connection to kafka. Which extra option do I need to avoid this error? There was no such error observed in Java codebase which is connecting to same kafka cluster.

Successful logs :

```
2019-03-15T07:15:24.364Z - [32minfo[39m: Producer receipt-svc#producer-1 ready
2019-03-15T07:15:24.410Z - [32minfo[39m: Consumer receipt-svc#consumer-2 ready
2019-03-15T07:15:24.411Z - [32minfo[39m: Subscribing to following topics : XXXX.XXXX.XXXX,XXXX.XXXX.XXXX,XXXX.XXXX.XXXX
2019-03-15T07:15:24.462Z - [32minfo[39m: Consumer receipt-svc#consumer-3 ready
2019-03-15T07:15:24.463Z - [32minfo[39m: Subscribing to following topics : XXXX.XXXX.XXXX
```

Error logs :

```
<------Kafka event log : Start ------->

2019-03-16T12:25:25.629Z - [32minfo[39m:  severity=4, fac=METADATA, message=[thrd:main]: sasl_ssl://sl73kfkapp002.visa.com:8443/43: Metadata request failed: periodic refresh: Local: Required feature not supported by broker (0ms): Permanent

2019-03-16T12:25:25.630Z - [32minfo[39m: <------Kafka event log : End ------->

2019-03-17T12:30:26.301Z - [32minfo[39m: <------Kafka event log : Start ------->

2019-03-17T12:30:26.302Z - [32minfo[39m:  severity=4, fac=METADATA, message=[thrd:main]: sasl_ssl://sl73kfkapp002.visa.com:8443/43: Metadata request failed: refresh unavailable topics: Local: Required feature not supported by broker (0ms): Permanent

2019-03-17T12:30:26.303Z - [32minfo[39m: <------Kafka event log : End ------->
```

Above logs are printed from following code piece

```js
const consumer = new Kafka.KafkaConsumer(
      {
        "client.id": config["client.id"],
        "group.id": config["group.id"],
        "security.protocol": config["security.protocol"],
        "metadata.broker.list": config["metadata.broker.list"],
        "ssl.ca.location": config["ssl.ca.location"],
        "ssl.certificate.location": config["ssl.certificate.location"],
        "ssl.key.location": config["ssl.key.location"],
        "ssl.key.password": this.machineKey.decrypt(config["ssl.key.password"]),
        "sasl.kerberos.service.name": config["sasl.kerberos.service.name"],
        "sasl.kerberos.principal": config["sasl.kerberos.principal"],
        "sasl.kerberos.keytab": config["sasl.kerberos.keytab"]
      },
      {
        "auto.offset.reset": "beginning",
        "enable.auto.commit": true
      }
    );

consumer.on("event.log", function(log) {
      logger.info("<------Kafka event log : Start ------->");
      logger.info(log);
      logger.info("<------Kafka event log : End ------->");
    });

    consumer.on("ready", function(arg) {
      logger.info(`Consumer ${arg.name} ready`);
      logger.info("Subscribing to following topics : " + topics);
      consumer.subscribe(topics);
      consumer.consume();
    });

    consumer.connect();
```

Comment: What version are the brokers running? For issues like this, you probably want to open a ticket against node-rdkafka: https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka

Comment: Broker version is 0.11.0.3. I'll add to my original post. Thanks for the link, would add there as well.

Comment: It looks like the [issue there](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/issues/590) has no activity and it was closed on Jun/2019.

Comment: @hudibaba did you find the solution to your problem? If you did, could you post the answer back here so the community can benefit from it?